# IE7 <button> and <input type=button/submit> weird styling?

Tags: css, button, input, internet-explorer-7, border

IE is driving me crazy.

See the following page: http://goo.gl/uRGsh

In IE8+ the buttons in the content looks and behaves relatively ok, but for some reason the buttons are given a white border and thick black outline when focused in IE7. I've tried removing the outline with `outline: none;`, which does absolutely nothing for me.

Another disturbing thing is that the text in the buttons kind of jump down on focus. I'm not sure what causes this; it can't be padding, can it? Because then the button would grow in size. Am i missing something? The buttons jump in all IE for me. I have custom hover/focus states with backgrounds, so i don't want the jumpyness.

Any ideas how to get rid of the border/outline and the jumping?

Comment: try border: 0; or border-style: none;

Comment: @Rob: Not by choice. Kyle: The buttons actually have a blue border, it just as if IE7 overrides my button styling. Check in IE8 and compare with IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Remove outline from image link

```
    a img {outline : none;}
```

Remove border from image link

```
    img {border : 0;}
```

Good Luck..)

Comment: I don't see how that would work though; the buttons aren't links or images, they're `<input type="submit">`, `<input type="button">` or `<button>`. I've tried disabling the outline with no success. I don't want to remove the border because it already has a blue border, it's just as if IE7 doesn't care and applies it's own styling.

Answer (score 0):

Also - for this type of issue consider using the html5 shiv

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```